# How to split image into Hex-Code pixels?

Tags: javascript, php, css

Good evening :)

First of all I'm sorry for my bad english

Here's my problem:
I want to create a script (PHP, HTML, JavaScript, ...) where I can upload an image then click "enter" and the script will convert the immage into a new image with 36x84 pixels. The script returns only Hex-Codes for each pixel. This means that theres only one red color, one orange, etc.

Do you have any idea? I have no idea where to start.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you can do this in two steps.
1) Create the new 36x84 image from the uploaded image using `imagecopyresampled` function 
2) Use `imagecolorat` function to get the color of the new image at each pixel